# Converting Reflected Property to String

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got a problem converting an object property to string while using reflection...

```
string value = Convert.ToString(typeof(T).GetProperty(ValueField).GetValue(data, null));
```

This throws 'Object does not match target type.' when returning any type other than string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you don't want to use the property's `ToString` method, you can constrain `T` to classes that implement `IConvertible`:

```
public string DoSomething<T>(object data) where T: IConvertible { ... }
```

Comment: While the other two solutions are more pragmatical, I give you +1 as well for solving the problem in another way.

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed that this was due to question-induced-tunnel-vision for my initial answer, so many thanks :) (Plus, it's possible that someone might override ToString and IConvertible.ToString in different ways.)

Comment: As awesome as your answer is. I have to note that i was pointing the GetValue to the collection instead of the correct object... :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the type's built-in `ToString` method instead of calling `Convert.ToString`. All types have a `ToString` method inherited from `object`, whereas `Convert.ToString` only works for types that implement the `IConvertible` interface.

```
string value =
    typeof(T).GetProperty(ValueField).GetValue(data, null).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast every object to a string, but every object has a ToString method.  So you can change your code to:

```
string value = typeof(T).GetProperty(ValueField).GetValue(data, null).ToString();
```